# SL error for using count(*) in join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to use the below query in a stored procedure to get everything from Promotion table and count(*) from Merchant_Views table. But i get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.". This is in SQl Server 2005. I am wonddering how this can be solved. What am i doing wrong. Thanks for all the help!

```
SELECT *, (count(*) from Merchant_Views) FROM dbo.Promotion
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Location ON dbo.Promotion.LocationID = dbo.Merchant_Location.LocationID
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Views MV ON MV.LocationID = dbo.Promotion.LocationID
and dbo.Merchant_Views.ClickDate >= dbo.Promotion.startDate 
and dbo.Merchant_Views.ClickDate <=  dbo.Promotion.expireDate
and dbo.Merchant_Views.Status <> 'printed' 
WHERE dbo.Promotion.MerchantID=@MerchantID AND PostType=@PostType
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Where's the COUNT(*) portion of code that you mention?

Comment: My bad!! Look at the query now. Thank you!

Comment: What is it supposed to do then? All the answers so far look wrong to me. Presumably you are trying to count the `Merchant_Views` related to a particular `Promotion` not just count all of them? What are your table structures?

Comment: @MartinSmith you are right. I am trying to get the number of rows for each Promotion, not for all of them. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing a SELECT before COUNT(*)

```
SELECT *, ViewCnt
FROM dbo.Promotion p
     INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Location ml ON p.LocationID = ml.LocationID
     INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Views mv ON mv.LocationID = p.LocationID
     INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT p.ID, COUNT(*) AS ViewCnt
      FROM dbo.Promotion p
           INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Views mv ON mv.LocationID = p.LocationID
      GROUP BY p.Id) t ON t.ID = p.ID
WHERE p.MerchantID= @MerchantID AND PostType=@PostType
  AND MV.ClickDate >= p.startDate 
  AND MV.ClickDate <=  p.expireDate
  AND MV.Status <> 'printed'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) from Merchant_Views) FROM dbo.Promotion P
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Location ML ON P.LocationID = ML.LocationID
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Views MV ON MV.LocationID = P.LocationID
and MV.ClickDate >= P.startDate 
and MV.ClickDate <=  P.expireDate
and MV.Status <> 'printed' 
WHERE P.MerchantID=@MerchantID AND PostType=@PostType
```

**Edit**

are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT count(P.PromotionID) AS COUNT  --,   MV.column1, mv.column2 --and so on..
FROM dbo.Promotion P
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Location ML ON P.LocationID = ML.LocationID
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Views MV ON MV.LocationID = P.LocationID
and MV.ClickDate >= P.startDate 
and MV.ClickDate <=  P.expireDate
and MV.Status <> 'printed' 
WHERE P.MerchantID=@MerchantID AND PostType=@PostType
--group by --  MV.column1, mv.column2 --and so on..
```

Comment: @Ram are you trying to get the count of every merchant view related to the promotions? If so, you need to specify the column names instead of the "*", and the select would be different and you should need some group bys, if yo want the count

Comment: I need to get the number of rows count for each PromotionID. I am sorry for the confusion and thanks for your time correcting me...

Comment: I guess yes, I also need to get everything from Promotion table along with The count(of PromotionID) in Merchant_Views table.

Comment: ok, just add them in the select and in the group by thats why I just added them as comment's column1, column2, column3 etc, i dont know the complete structure of your table select P.Column1, P.Column2, Mv.Column1, Mv.Column2.....
group by P.Column1, P.Column2, Mv.Column1, Mv.Column2

Comment: One last question, I have 12 columns in Promotion table. Can't we write select * from Promotion and Select count(*) for each PromotionID in Merchant_Views?? Because adding each column to group by and select is kind of big. I am just curious if we can do this way. Thank you so muchhh

Comment: Try to use SELECT distinct *,count(p.fieldname) ...... I hope I got you right here.

Comment: Fantastic it is.. Thank you so much for your time. :-) Means a lot!!

Comment: You could do it that way, but when you dont have any count, or max or any agreggate function, in this case you are having count.. so you need to explicit specify the columns and the group by.. in other cases, you could use, P.*, MV.*,  but im not sure if in this case the select distinct *, will work in all cases..

Answer (score 1):

Yes You would REALLY want to use a group by with an aggregation (count()) here.

```
SELECT p.field,p.field2.p.field3,ml.f1,ml.f2,ml.f3,mv.f1,mv.f2,mv.f3, count(mv.*) FROM dbo.Promotion P
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Location ML ON P.LocationID = ML.LocationID
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Views MV ON MV.LocationID = P.LocationID
and MV.ClickDate >= P.startDate 
and MV.ClickDate <=  P.expireDate
and MV.Status <> 'printed' 
WHERE P.MerchantID=@MerchantID AND PostType=@PostType
group by p.field,p.field2.p.field3,ml.f1,ml.f2,ml.f3,mv.f1,mv.f2,mv.f3
```

Comment: Be weary of the performance there --- the group by, and all the joins would want correct indexes set. The SELECT * is a bad thing to do especially on big tables mate. I'm just warning you. You should check your execution plans carefully.

Comment: Yeah, i should really see this carefully. Thank you for the advice Mr.Benner.

Answer (score 0):

You need a SELECT on the inner query.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) FROM Merchant_Views) FROM dbo.Promotion
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because ofthis clause in select

```
(count(*) from Merchant_Views)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a SELECT in your inner SELECT:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) from Merchant_Views) FROM dbo.Promotion
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Location ON dbo.Promotion.LocationID = dbo.Merchant_Location.LocationID
INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Views MV ON MV.LocationID = dbo.Promotion.LocationID
and dbo.Merchant_Views.ClickDate >= dbo.Promotion.startDate 
and dbo.Merchant_Views.ClickDate <=  dbo.Promotion.expireDate
and dbo.Merchant_Views.Status <> 'printed' 
WHERE dbo.Promotion.MerchantID=@MerchantID AND PostType=@PostType
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "dbo.Merchant_Views.ClickDate" could not be bound. This is the new error i get. Do i have to add group by ?? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you are getting thsi error because yo are using an Alias dbo.Merchant_Views MV

Comment: Without knowing the full data structure of your table, I don't know if I can help you fix that.  Sounds like maybe the column name may be wrong.

Comment: @GarrettVlieger - No. It's because `INNER JOIN dbo.Merchant_Views MV` gives an alias to `dbo.Merchant_Views` then later on it is being referenced as it's unaliased name which is invalid.